# Using the C# NHunspell how do I check words?

Tags: c#, spell-checking, hunspell, nhunspell

Using the C# NHunspell, how do I check if a word is spelled correctly and if not what the correct spelling is?

I've imported the NHunspell.dll into the project. And have looked at [the documentation](http://www.maierhofer.de/en/documentation/nhunspell/index.html).

But being a bit new at reading documentation it's hard to know where to start. Can someone provide an example on how to check if a word is spelled correctly? Basically I need a Helloworld for NHunspell.

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33658/NHunspell-Hunspell-for-the-NET-platform

Comment: Also, browse the unit tests: http://nhunspell.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/nhunspell/trunk/UnitTests/UnitTestsHunspell.cs?revision=81&view=markup

Comment: I actually ended up using NetSpell because it was easier to implement. Thank you though!

Answer (score 9):

```
using (Hunspell hunspell = new Hunspell("en_us.aff", "en_us.dic"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hunspell - Spell Checking Functions");
    Console.WriteLine("¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯¯");

    Console.WriteLine("Check if the word 'Recommendation' is spelled correct"); 
    bool correct = hunspell.Spell("Recommendation");
    Console.WriteLine("Recommendation is spelled " + 
       (correct ? "correct":"not correct"));

    Console.WriteLine("");
    Console.WriteLine("Make suggestions for the word 'Recommendatio'");
    List<string> suggestions = hunspell.Suggest("Recommendatio");
    Console.WriteLine("There are " + 
       suggestions.Count.ToString() + " suggestions" );
    foreach (string suggestion in suggestions)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Suggestion is: " + suggestion );
    }
}
```

From the Article http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43495/Spell-Check-Hyphenation-and-Thesaurus-for-NET-with

Comment: how can we get all words? I mean scan each line of the dic file and get all combinations that can be produced from that line. how can i do that? ty

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43495/Spell-Check-Hyphenation-and-Thesaurus-for-NET-with?msg=5368357#xx5368357xx

Comment: When I try to implement this, I am getting error "AFF File not found". Where I can find or download it for hunspell.

Comment: You can get it from open office, there are dictioniaries for spell checking. Open it with 7zip or some other archive viewer and extract the files.

Comment: @ThomasMaierhofer - Can you please share any reference link to understand the purpose of AFF and .DIC file.

Comment: https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/releases
There is a file format PDF

Comment: @ThomasMaierhofer - I want to use MPL v1.1 in my .net project. Can you please share me the external or NuGet link to download this specific version for .Net.